# Eclipse Project Explorer: How do I get rid of ./ JS as working WebContent directory?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently synced up through SVN with a new project my team created. Upon checking out the project, my Project Explorer had a unique directory structure at first glance. It had the typical expected folders, but there was one directory marked

./

Which had the "JS" icon on it, and then all of the profile files+folders were under that directory, also with the "JS" icon.

Updating all plugins I have as well as tinkering with how I checkout did not seem to fix it.

I'm assuming there is some kind of property that I need to change within the project, but I have yet to find it. Also, I'm wondering if there is some kind of error before I even check out (so in our SVN) that would be causing it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: Here is a screenshot:

[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8887740/eclipse.png)

Comment: Thanks. Now, if you go to file system and try to find the same ./ directory, what is it named as? It could be a hidden file. So you may have to show them first.

Comment: an ls-a in the main directory does not yield any funky directory that his hidden. Also, the stuff under the ./ really just looks like a re-masking of what's in the root directory. Ex: everything under ./WebContent/ is also in the normal WebContent, etc. It seems like it is simply a malfunction in the actual explorer view.

Comment: UPDATE: It's a bug with the "Project Explorer". If anyone else is having problems with this, try using the "Package Explorer" or the "Navigator" view instead.

Comment: Oh is it? That's bad, isn't it?

Comment: OH! You meant "Package" explorer. I hadn't noticed the difference. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have one option for you which may work. Try creating a filter in the package explorer as shown in the below screenshots.

1. Click on the filter symbol on package explorer

   [image]
2. Click on the `Filters` option

   [image]
3. Type `./*` in the `Name filter patterns` free flowing text field

   [image]
4. Click OK and see if the strange directory still appears.

Comment: UPDATE: I noticed you meant the "Package Explorer". I was using the "Project Explorer". The weird directory pattern does not exist in the Package Explorer. Additionally the "Navigator" view does not have the weird directory pattern. I think it might simply be a bug with the Project Explorer, therefore I'll move to one of the other two views, and that should be a very reasonable solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Update to Helios.  http://bugs.eclipse.org/274550#c3